# Kendo Grid dataItem selection is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have two kendo grids in a page, I am trying to transfer some items from one grid to another on button click . my code is working perfectly in Chrome but not in IE.

```
$('#btn_move_1_2').on('click', function(){
    var grid1 = $('#grid1').data('kendoGrid');
    var grid2 = $('#grid2').data('kendoGrid');
    grid1.select().each(function(key , value){

        var currItem = grid1.dataItem(value);
        grid1.dataSource.remove(currItem);
        //on second iteration gets error- Unable to get property 'uid' of undefined or null reference
        grid2.dataSource.add(currItem);
    });
    grid1.select().each(function(){ grid1.removeRow($(this)); });
    grid2.refresh();
});
```

single selection will work fine. on multiple selection it broke in second iteration with error "Unable to get property 'uid' of undefined or null reference"

I created a sample snippet to show the error http://dojo.telerik.com/@jomet/oVICI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet. Instead of passing full TR declaration I am passing only the row's unique Id to get the modal/item detail.

```
$('#btn_move_1_2').on('click', function () {
    var grid1 = $('#grid1').data('kendoGrid');
    var grid2 = $('#grid2').data('kendoGrid');
    var rowSelected = grid1.select();

    grid1.select().each(function (key, value) { 
        // I have updated below code line
        var currItem = grid1.dataSource.getByUid($(value).data('uid'));
        grid1.dataSource.remove(currItem); 
        grid2.dataSource.add(currItem);
    });
    grid1.select().each(function () { grid1.removeRow($(this)); });
    grid2.refresh();
});
```

Let me know if any concern.